# Chain Hash Table Link list

Tags: java, hashtable, chaining

I am supposed to make a chain hash table to put names in each bucket as a linked list. I know how to do this with buckets that hold one value but I do not know how to put a link list in each bucket. I have a person class with first and last name already as well as a hashcode class. I have written remove but I am not sure how to put a LinkedList into the method. I also have a bucketList class; is this where I need to implement the LinkedList? If I can get some pointers on what do on the remove or put methods, I should be able to figure out how to do the rest. Thank you

```
    public class MyChainHashTable<K, V> {

private static final int BUCKET_COUNT = 10;

private BucketList[] buckets = new BucketList[BUCKET_COUNT];

private void remove(K key, V value) {
    int bucketIndex = key.hashCode(); //TODO
    int bucketsProbed = 0;

    while (!buckets[bucketIndex].isEmptySinceStart() && bucketsProbed < BUCKET_COUNT) {
        // if this bucket isn't empty, and it matches what we're looking for
        if (!buckets[bucketIndex].isEmpty()
                && buckets[bucketIndex].getElement().equals(value)) {
            buckets[bucketIndex].clear();
            return;
        }
        bucketsProbed++;
        bucketIndex++;
        bucketIndex %= BUCKET_COUNT;   // circle back to 0
    }
}

private boolean put(K key, V value) {
    return false;

}

private void showTable() {
    // old phone UI
    String[] keyBoard = {"1    ", "2 ABC", "3 DEF", "4 GHI", "5 JKL",
            "6 MNO", "7 PRS", "8 TUV", "9 WXY", "0    "};

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Why have you declared `buckets` as an array of buckit **lists**?  And how is `BucketList` declared?

Comment: In a conventional Java hash table, each bucket is simply a place where you put the first link of a hashchain.  So the `buckets` array should be a `HashChainNode[]`

Comment: BucketList<T> generically

Comment: And what does it comprise?

Comment: For hints on how to implement a linked list, you could start by looking at the Wikipedia page on linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I gather you want to implement a hash table with linked lists. I also saw this comment

> BucketList generically – Rawsick

So let me try and implement parts of this data structure.

Let's start with BucketList. Since this sounds like a just a Bucket with a generic parameter T defining the bucket and V which is what's in the bucket. I'm gonna refactor it to `Bucket<T, V>`

```
public class Bucket<T extends Colletion<V>, V> {
    private T bucket;

    public T add(V value) {
        return bucket.add(V);
    }
    // More functions here
}
```

Now the hash table,

```
public class MyChainHashTable<K, V> {
    private static final int BUCKET_COUNT = 10;
    // Advisable to use a resizeable array here, like an ArrayList
    // No need for bucket count then
    private Bucket<LinkedList, V>[] buckets = new Bucket<>[BUCKET_COUNT];

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        int bucketIndex = key.hashCode() % BUCKET_COUNT;
        buckets[bucketIndex].add(V);
    }
    // More functions here
}
```

This was a very simple approach to a hash table, only the bucket itself was slightly complicated in that the bucket could store values in the form of any class from the Java Collections framework.

I would advise reading into the source code of several popular implementations of collections in Java. You will get a better idea of how to approach problems like this.

Check out google's [Gauva](https://github.com/google/guava) library. Look at some of the complex collections like MultiMap and go through how they implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Chained HashTable is really a HashTable of HashTables which maps your hash key to a HashTable so that you don't have to jump around the table when you have key collisions.

Your asking for a variant of that with a HashTable of LinkedLists instead of a HashTable of HashTables.

In a basic HashTable you need to compute the next index to try when you get a key collision, basically what your doing with `bucketIndex %= BUCKET_COUNT;` but with a chained HashTable you don't do that. Instead of inserting your element at the indexed location in your underlying array, your array is an array of HashTables (or an array of LinkedLists in your case) and you insert your elements into that collection.

Comment: A chained hash table (or a hash table which use *separate chaining*) stored linked lists at each bucket position. It it not a "hash table of hash tables".